# 503 error with Symfony 4 and Debug enabled

Tags: php, symfony, docker, symfony4, fpm

I have an issue with my Symfony 4.1 project. My server is on PHP FPM 7.2 and Apache 2.4.
When i enable the Debug component in a dev environment, i cannot access my application and i have a 503 error.
On the apache server, i can see this error:

```
AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
```

no error in the fpm container.
At first i thought about a memory_limit issue, but the error disappear when i activate XDebug on the fpm container. And XDebug eats quite a lot of memory, so i don't know where is the problem.

If anybody has any idea, it will be really appreciated.

Thx,
JM

Comment: I still don't know where it comes from, but i downgraded my composer.json and composer.lock to Symfony 4.1.7 and the app is working fine. I will try to figure out when i'll have more time.

Comment: I retried to update and can't reproduce the issue. This question can be closed.

Comment: And the issue came back. I'm not the only one to have it: https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-4-1-8-released#comment-22855

Comment: I think I’m having the same problem. I’ve a local installation of the Kimai time tracker, based on Symfony, that return a 503 HTTP error when in production mode (production dependencies, and `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`. There’s no problem when XDebug is disabled or when Kimai is in dev mode. When enabled, it fails everytime in Symfony `\Symfony\Component\VarExporter\Internal\Registry:63`. My PHP version is 7.4.13 with XDebug 3.0.0. Symfony is 4.4.10.